# Form Builder views

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design

Which among the following can be rated high considering the usability and promising a better experience while building forms?
[image: Two panel form builder]
[image: Common layout]

Comment: Why not just ask your users? Better yet, make it a configuration option, like Visual Studio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would just keep fields in the left side menu. Field properties panel could be a floating panel that appears on selecting a field. Similar to how Balsamiq does it. The form properties could a panel or dialog getting invoked by an action or icon in the main navigation or you could think of placing it in the fields panel.

Suggesting this on the assumption that fields and field properties will be frequently used by the users and form properties not that much.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the space needed for the form, i would choose the second one, one click less.

And it depend of what you propose in form properties but it can be before or after this screen (I mean by steps)